# how to update the date in android DatePicker widget

Tags: android, datepicker, widget, updatedate

Hey,
I want to update the date to a year before 1970.
the updateDate function wants a date since 1970.

the widget itself allow you to select 1900-2100 (from what i read you can change it also using an xml to describe the control)

any solutions?
if not, what widget do you use to select date (e.g. birth date...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a negative number when you pass in the years.